# How to add serializer in dart to convert iso 8601 to datetime object?

Tags: dart, flutter, datetime-format, iso8601

In dart I want to do this:

```
var s = "2018-11-23T04:25:41.9241411Z";  // string comes from a json but represented here for simplicity like this
var d = DateTime.parse(s);
```

but it throws a null.

Dart can't seem to parse iso 8601 date time formats.  I've found a custom serializer called "Iso8601DateTimeSerializer" but how do I add it to my flutter app?

links:  https://reviewable.io/reviews/google/built_value.dart/429#-

The instructions here only indicate adding it to dart using "SerializersBuilder.add" but I'm a newbie and cant find out how?

link: 
 https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/built_value/latest/iso_8601_date_time_serializer/Iso8601DateTimeSerializer-class.html

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that Dart's [`DateTime.parse`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html) only accepts up to six digits of fractional seconds, and your input has seven.

> ... and then optionally a '.' followed by a one-to-six digit second fraction.

You can sanitize your input down to six digits using something like:

```
String restrictFractionalSeconds(String dateTime) =>
    dateTime.replaceFirstMapped(RegExp(r"(\.\d{6})\d+"), (m) => m[1]);
```

Maybe the parse function should just accept more digits, even if they don't affect the value.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to Irn's answer. You need to add some escapes for the regex to work properly.

```
String restrictFractionalSeconds(String dateTime) =>
dateTime.replaceFirstMapped(RegExp("(\\.\\d{6})\\d+"), (m) => m[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it to the serializers builder.

Example:

```
@SerializersFor(models)
final Serializers serializers = (_$serializers.toBuilder()
      ..addPlugin(StandardJsonPlugin())
      ..add(Iso8601DateTimeSerializer()))
    .build();
```